# How can I stop messages that are not ready to be processed from entering this loop in the doIT() method?

Tags: java

when I set bpayrequestlist.size=maxmessagestoselect 1.e 20000, even messages which are not ready to be processed will enter the loop and it will turn into an infinite loop. How can I stop messages that are not ready to be processed from entering this loop?this is a banking system where messages like mt103 are being sent as a request by the customer. so those messages have to be processsed. i am encountering a problem in the while condition: `while (bpayRequestsList!=null && bpayRequestsList.size() == maxMessagesToSelect);`:

```
public class PaymentRequestPlugin implements IPlugin
    {
        BpayDeliveryService bpayDeliveryService = BpayDeliveryService.instance();
        private final int ORACLE_MAX_IN_ELEMENTS = 1000;
        private static final int MAX_SELECT_DEFAULT_VALUE = 20000;

       private int maxMessagesToSelect = MAX_SELECT_DEFAULT_VALUE;
                    private Theme PAYMENT_REQUEST_PLUGIN = new Theme("PAYMENT_REQUEST_PLUGIN");
        KundenZahlung kuza = null;
        List<Long> kuzaList = new ArrayList<Long>();
        List<Long> updatedBpayRequests = new ArrayList<Long>();
        private BpayDeliveryService bpay = BpayDeliveryService.instance();


        @Override
        public void doIt() throws PluginException
        {
            List<BpayPaymentRequestData> bpayRequestsList = null;
            Trace.trace(PAYMENT_REQUEST_PLUGIN, "PaymentRequestPlugin doIt()");
            do
            {
                try
                {
                    bpayRequestsList = bpay.getPaymentRequestPending(maxMessagesToSelect);
                    int lIndex = 0;
                    int uIndex = 0;
                    while (uIndex < bpayRequestsList.size())
                    {
                        uIndex = uIndex + ORACLE_MAX_IN_ELEMENTS;
                        if (uIndex > bpayRequestsList.size())
                        {
                            uIndex = bpayRequestsList.size();
                        }
                        List<BpayPaymentRequestData> bpayRequestsListAtOnce = bpayRequestsList.subList(lIndex, uIndex);
                        doAtOnce(bpayRequestsListAtOnce);
                        lIndex = uIndex;
                    }
                }
                catch (PluginException pe)
                {
                   pe.notifyEvent();               
                }
                catch (MVServiceNotAvailableException e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            while (bpayRequestsList!=null && bpayRequestsList.size() == maxMessagesToSelect);

        }
```

Comment: Which information in your code indicates that a message is not ready to be processed  ?

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a [mcve].

Comment: If a method called `bpay.getPaymentRequestPending()` returns payment requests that aren't pending, there is something wrong with it, and not something that appears here in the code you've posted. Unclear what you're asking.

Comment: this is a banking system where messages like mt103 are being sent as a request by the customer. so those messages have to be processsed

Comment: while (bpayRequestsList!=null && bpayRequestsList.size() == maxMessagesToSelect);   i am encountering a glitch in this while condition as it will always process the messages even if they are not in the ready state to be processed.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There are a few options I can suggest one would be utilized an array of objects and pass the message with a boolean value to it and this element of one would create an array of objects
Ex.

```
 Public class objectOfOne
 {
      Public string message;
      Public boolean truth;
      //Constructor
      Public class objectOfOne (String        m; boolean t)
      {
            Message = m;
            Truth= true;
       }
       //Insert get and set methods here 
       // So you can update if message
       // Was processed

  }//End objectOfOne class
```

In your main driver  you'd call this to return The message to be processed after being processed you'd set the boolean for the object to true

Eg your if statement to check if message has been processed would be something like...

```
   If(ArrayObject [at index].getTruth() == true)
```

Then process message

This is the way I would handle such a task it may not be the best way to do this but it's the best way I know how to do what I think your asking.

Comment: This does not even compile...

Comment: it wouldnt compile as i have just put a part of the code